# Rails API not able to destroy session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails API and devise for authentication but when sending a request to destroy the session, it doesn't return any response other then status 200.It returns the same response no matter if the user exists, is logged in or the password is incorrect.

url `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in`

I'm sending a DELETE request through Postman and it just returns a 200 response. It should be returning the data which is stored in the `@message`

```
{
    "user":{
        "email":"abc@abc.com",
        "password":"abc@abc.com"
    }
}
```

I even tried to destory the session using the session id:

`curl -X DELETE -d "3" http://localhost:3000/users/sign_out`

sessions_controller.rb

```
class API::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(user_params[:email])
    if @user && @user.valid_password?(user_params[:password])
      session[:user_id]=@user.id
      sign_in :user, @user
      render json: @user
    elsif @user && not(@user.valid_password?(user_params[:password]))
      invalid_attempt
    else
      no_user
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @message = "signed out"
    session.delete(:user_id)
    sign_out(@user)
    render json: @message
  end

  private

  def no_user
    render json: {error: "An account with this email doesn't exist. Please create a new one"}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

  def invalid_attempt
    render json: { error: "Your password isn't correct" }, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
 devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'api/v1/registrations', sessions:'api/v1/sessions'}
```